# Laravel: Expect String Error for Google DocAI - but variable is string

Tags: php, laravel, string, cloud-document-ai

i am trying to use DocAI Api to parse invoices. I am using Laravel, but i dont know why the validation for string doesn't work correctly - my variable is a string but doesnt pass the checkstring function, it returns me:

```
InvalidArgumentException

  Expect string.

  at vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil.php:97
     93▕
     94▕     public static function checkString(&$var, $check_utf8)
     95▕     {
     96▕         if (is_array($var) || is_object($var)) {
  ➜  97▕             throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Expect string.");
     98▕         }
     99▕         if (!is_string($var)) {
    100▕             $var = strval($var);
    101▕         }

  1   vendor\google\cloud-document-ai\src\V1\ProcessRequest.php:252
      Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkString(Object(Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\ProcessRequest))

  2   vendor\google\cloud-document-ai\src\V1\Gapic\DocumentProcessorServiceGapicClient.php:1807
      Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\ProcessRequest::setName(Object(Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\ProcessRequest))
```

This is my command code, i tried in multiple ways to solve that - but i think i have to change the vendor package....

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\ProcessDocumentAI;
use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\DocumentProcessorServiceClient;
use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\GcsOutputConfig;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Google_Service_Storage;
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;
use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\ProcessRequest;
use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\GcsDocument;

class ProcessExistingDocuments extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'process:existing-documents';
    protected $description = 'Process existing documents in the Google Cloud Storage bucket using Document AI';

    public function handle()
    {
        $keyFilePath = 'app/credentials/sunlsds.json';

        $credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
            $keyFilePath
        );

        // Create a Google Cloud Storage service instance
        $storage = new Google_Service_Storage(['credentials' => $credentials]);

        $documentAiClient = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient([
            'credentials' => $credentials,
        ]);

        $bucketName = 'a';

        $storageObjects = $storage->objects->listObjects($bucketName);


        foreach ($storageObjects->getItems() as $object) {

            $gcsUri = 'gs://' . $bucketName . '/' . $object->name;

            $objectName = $object->name;

            // Skip processing if the object is a directory
            if ($object->size === 0 || substr($objectName, -1) === '/') {
                continue;
            }

            $allowedExtensions = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];
            $fileExtension = pathinfo($objectName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (!in_array(strtolower($fileExtension), $allowedExtensions)) {
                continue; // Skip files with unsupported extensions
            }

            $gcsDocument = (new GcsDocument())
                ->setGcsUri($gcsUri);

            $processRequest = (new ProcessRequest())
                ->setGcsDocument($gcsDocument)
                ->setName('projects/projectid/locations/us/processors/id8');

            $operationResponse = $documentAiClient->processDocument($processRequest);

            dd($operationResponse);

            // Wait for the operation to complete
            $operationResponse->pollUntilComplete();

            if ($operationResponse->operationSucceeded()) {
                $processedDocument = $operationResponse->getResult();

                // Now you can extract information from $processedDocument
                // Implement your logic to extract supplier_name and recipient_name
                // based on the extracted data

                // Once you have the supplier_name and recipient_name, you can update
                // the file path in Google Cloud Storage and move the document
                $newFilePath = 'invoices/an/luna/companie/' . $object->name();
                $newObject = $storage->objects->copy($bucketName, $object->name(), $bucketName, $newFilePath);
                $storage->objects->delete($bucketName, $object->name());
            } else {
                $this->error('Document processing failed: ' . $operationResponse->getError());
            }
        }

        $this->info('Document processing completed.');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the trace? Maybe something else is calling setName

Comment: That's all.. it's the response that i have in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the value has to be string, i changed the processRequest from package.

Instead of return $this, i changed the function with return $this->name..

```
public function setName($var) {
    GPBUtil::checkString($var, True);
    $this->name = $var;

    return $this->name; }
```